# Why does this regular expression won't work properly?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm in the need to check wether some input is strictly as this one:

`PEOPLE-123456` or `PERSON-12345376` (it can be any combination of numbers)

The number of numbers following the `-` doesn't matter. It can be from 0 to N numbers.

I've come up with the following expression:

`/(PEOPLE-)|(PERSON-)?=^[0-9]+$/`

The problem is, this will work even if the characters after the `-`are not numbers.

- PEOPLE-123131 yields `true`
- PERSON-123242 yields `true`
- PERSON-23123.341 yields `true`
- PEOPLE-.2341231 yields `false`

What am I doing wrong with it? I don't see any problems with the expression itself, maybe I am to noob to see it.

Comment: Visualize it and you will see your bug https://regexper.com/#%2F(PEOPLE-)%7C(PERSON-)%3F%3D%5E%5B0-9%5D%2B%24%2F

Comment: The listed results do not match the provided regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the grouping parentheses around both alternatives:

```
/^(PEOPLE|PERSON)-\d+$/
```

And you shouldn't mark it optional with `?`. I have no idea why you put `=` and `^` after that part.

And if you want to allow decimal points in the number, use `[0-9.]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: I think OP was trying to do a positive lookahead, although unnecessary and the syntax was slightly off. Not sure where the `^` came from though.

Comment: Yup. I was trying to do a positive lookahead. I got it wrong from the book I read it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(PERSON|PEOPLE)-[0-9]{1,}$
```

This ensures the beginnings starts with exactly wither `PERSON` or `PEOPLE`, followed by `-` and ends with at least one number.

Comment: `[0-9]{1,}` -> `[0-9]+` -> `\d+`

Comment: Sure, it's all the same. I find `[0-9]{1,}` more readable and easy to understand for a newbe.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if numbers are optional. Otherwise at least 1 number is required replace * with +.

```
/^(PEOPLE|PERSON)-\d*$/
```